# I don't have notifications when changing the brightness

Tags: grub2, brightness, notification, notify-osd, function-keys

In order to have the brightness feature working on my EeePC (Ubuntu 13.10, kernel 3.13), I had to add to my `/etc/default/grub` :

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"

It was only displaying notifications of brightness change, but was never changing the brightness. Now it does, but I have lost the notifications.

Not a big deal, but I don't understand. Can you help ?

Comment: Do you have the problem with the kernel that's currently in main (3.11.0-15-generic). If you don't have a problem with the older kernel you may have found a bug. Worth reporting?

Comment: Yes, same problem occurs, whether I use 3.13 (from kernel.org) or 3.11 (from official repos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Ubuntu (same version exactly), but without the manual update to 3.13 from Kernel.org : it works flawlessly with stock 3.11 kernel from Ubuntu.

I think that :

- 3.13 from Kernel.org needs `acpi_osi=Linux` to have brightness control but it breaks notifications
- 3.11 from Ubuntu works "as it", but adding `acpi_osi=Linux` also breaks the notifications, so it isn't needed.